# How to confirm that a cloned external hard drive is accurately cloned?

Tags: terminal, hard-drive, backup, ssd, carbon-copy-cloner

I've used Carbon Copy Cloner to copy one external SSD, which is currently about to die, to another one. I also have an online backup of the external drive, but I want to confirm that my cloned copy is exactly the same as the old one.

I can compare individual files using `md5sum`. Is there a tool I can use to compare every single file on two drives?

Comment: See this answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/382345/119271

Comment: Doesn't CCC verify its copy anyway automatically?

Comment: @nohillside I believe it does verify its copy but it is always good to be able to do an independent verification of your own!

Answer (score 1):

I've found a way to use some command line tools to recursively check hashes of the individual files. Here's my commands:

1. `hashdeep -rel -r . > hashdeep-outout.txt`

Hashdeep (which you can install via homebrew) will create a CSV file listing each individual file with various hashes including MD5 and SHA256. `-rel` lists the files with the relative path to the CWD, so I can run this command on *both* the old drive, and the new cloned drive, and the file names will be identical.

2. `sort --field-separator=',' --key=4 hashdeep-output.txt > hashdeep-sorted.txt`

This sorts the CSV file by filename (the 4th field), so that when I compare the two files (for the old drive, and the new drive) everything will be in the same order.

3. Then I use just `diff` to compare the sorted output files. If there is anything which was copied incorrectly, it will let me know because the hashes won't match up.

Comment: How can `hashdeep` get installed?

Comment: @nohillside Through `homebrew`

Comment: Maybe you could mention that in your answer, not everybody is aware of this.

Comment: CCC is an rsync client, which uses file checksums by default for file comparison during the copy. I usually run it a second time in case anything got corrupted. That's reassuring enough for me, but I understand why you might want to manually verify. I voted up your answer.